# Rails twitter gem causing error Missing required parameter: status

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, rubygems, twitter-gem

I am using [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) with rails in order to retrive the user timeline and post an update:

```
  def index
    @tweets = Twitter.home_timeline
  end

  def tweet
    text = params[:text]
    Twitter.update(text) unless text = nil
  end
```

The view which sends the request via jquery/ajax:

```
<input type="text" class="tweet-box" placeholder="tweet something" />
<input type="submit" class="tweet-button" value="tweet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".tweet-button").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/twitters/tweet', { text: $(".tweet-box").val() });
    });
</script>
```

finally the routes:

```
get "twitters/index"
post "twitters/tweet"
```

getting the timeline works fine, however when trying to send the update, i get this error:

> Missing required parameter: status

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"unless text = nil"

This is *setting* text TO nil, so there is no text being passed into update()

A good habit is to always put the literal on the left:

nil == text

That way if you for get == and do = it will fail because you can't assign to a literal.

try either "unless text == nil" or "unless text.nil?"

Answer (score 0):

In my case with the same error message, it turned out that my equivalent of your text variable was an empty string.  You check for nil?  Try checking for empty?

Comment: i checked the value, both in firebug and rails `render` and it exists.